# Is there limit to the ttl param of the google calendar watch api?

Tags: node.js, google-calendar-api

I've been working on google calendar sync in node js. I want the notification channel for watching the events to be active forever, but I found that the time to live parameter is defaulted to 3600 seconds. Is there a limit to the value I can give as the time to live? The idea is to give a high enough value so that the channel lives practically for ever. Will this work? Or is it better to refresh these channels now and then?

Thanks in advance :) .

Comment: Not sure where you are getting 3600 from but once the web hook is active it should continue to send you data https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push

Comment: @DaImTo It says here that the ttl parameter defaults to 3600s. https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/watch.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum time is `2592000` seconds, or in other words 30 days.

This is not defined in the documentation, but if you try to set `ttl` to 50 years, or 60 days, it will set the expiration to 30 days from the point you created the notification channel.

Side-note: default is `604800` (at least this year)